# Elements in a convex set, regarding distance

Tags: analysis

I am looking at a much bigger proof than this, but this step is bugging me a lot. Suppose that $\Omega$ is a convex set and that $x,y\in \Omega$ are two elements in the set such that $|x-y|<r_1 + r_2$ for two arbitrary positive constants $r_1,r_2$. If the set is convex, how can I assure that there exists $z$ such that $|x-z|<r_1$ and $|y-z|<r_2$?

Comment: Take a $z$ strategically chosen on the segment between $x$ and $y$. The numbers $r_1$ and $r_2$ should probably appear in the definition of $z$.

Comment: Let $\phi(t) = y+t(x-y)$, with $t \in (0,1)$. Then $|x-y|=|x-\phi(t)|+|\phi(t)-y|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was actually right away. Thanks for both suggestions, they were really helpful in my thought process. Define $ z = \frac{r_2}{r_1 + r_2} x + \frac{r_1}{r_1 + r_2} y $.